# how to add listener to auto complete drop down list in android?

Tags: android

I have an auto-complete drop down list, I want to make some action when I click on one item in the list.. is there any listener or event handler to to this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html), this will provide you method called setOnItemClickListener().

Comment: how can i get the string text of the selected item ?? ,, where i need to implement this method public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
   view. 
   }    right ??

Comment: Make a class which implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener and  in that method called  getItemAtPosition(position) will help you to get the data. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html

Answer (score 0):

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener searchItemClicked = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {
    //your code here
    }
}
```

It's important to note that OnItemSelectedListener does not activate when a user selects a dropdown.