# Accessing objects dynamically created with an adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner, simpleadapter, android-viewbinder

I've created a dynamic `ListView` with `TextView`s and `Spinner`s, using a `SimpleAdapter` and a `ViewBinder`.

**How can I access a `Spinner` value after the user had selected it?**

I think I need to create references to the spinners inside my `ViewBinder`, but I don't know how. I tried this but it's not working:

```
public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data,
                                String textRepresentation) {

mySpinner = (Spinner) view;

}
```

Comment: I think this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1337424/android-spinner-get-the-selected-item-change-event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener l)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Spinner.html)

Also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633315/how-to-add-listener-to-auto-complete-drop-down-list-in-android/4633327#4633327).

Hope this helps.